# How to close udp socket correctly, python

Tags: python, sockets

I have a small issue.

How can I close UDP-socket on the server-side correctly? Below you can find a part of my code. I guess, you do not need the whole code for my case.

**Server Code**

```
import ns_beam  # my module
import socket
import pickle

host = socket.gethostname()
port_client = 60000
port_server = 50000
CLIENT_ADDRESS = (host, port_client)

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind((host, port_server))

while True:
    message, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    recv_data = pickle.loads(message)  # convert data to pickle
    print(f"Received force from PS = {round(recv_data, 3)} [kN]")

    result = ns_beam.num_sub_structure(f_sensor=recv_data, num_elem_tot=element_number)  #  calculation
    print(f"Displacement of NS = {round(result, 3)} [mm]")

    # code to send data
    sent_data = pickle.dumps(result)       # convert data to pickle
    server_socket.sendto(sent_data,        # data to be sent
                         CLIENT_ADDRESS)   # details of destination

server_socket.close()
```

**Client Code**

```
import ps_truss # my module
import socket
import pickle
import time

host = socket.gethostname()
port_client = 60000
port_server = 50000
SERVER_ADDRESS = (host, port_server)

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client_socket.bind((host, port_client))

# ===============================
# ===============================
# create an array for E_i, where every next E_i is 10% less than previous
E_arr = []
E = 210000  # [N/mm2]
E_0 = 210000  # [N/mm2]
while E > E_0 * 0.3:
    E = E - E * 0.1
    E_arr.append(E)
# ===============================
# ===============================

# ============ initial step. Start
result_init = ps_truss.ps_sub_structure(v_2=v_2_init, e_mod=E)  # calculation
# code to cent data
data_send_init = pickle.dumps(result_init)  # convert data to pickle
client_socket.sendto(data_send_init,  # data to be sent
                     SERVER_ADDRESS)  # details of destination
# ============ initial step. End


counter = 0

while True:

    for E_i in E_arr:
        message, address = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        recv_data = pickle.loads(message)
        print(f'received displacement from NS:{round(recv_data, 3)} [mm]')

        time.sleep(1)
        result = ps_truss.ps_sub_structure(v_2=recv_data, e_mod=E_i)  # calculation
        print(f'force from PS:{round(result, 3)} [kN]')

        # code to cent data
        sent_data = pickle.dumps(result)  # convert data to pickle
        client_socket.sendto(sent_data,  # data to be sent
                             SERVER_ADDRESS)  # details of destination

        counter += 1
        print(counter)
        if counter > len(E_arr):
            break
break

print("The client socket is closed")
client_socket.close()
```

On the Server Side the code `server_socket.close()` is unreachable. I understand, that first of all the while loop shall be closed.

My idea is as long I receive the data from client, the while loop will not be interrupted. If I do not receive data (e.g. for 30 sec.) the server shall close a socket.

Could you please help me to implement this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no connections in UDP

Comment: @user253751, sorry, My mistake. :) I meant "the server shall close a socket".

Comment: so I think your real question is how to know if nothing is received for 30 seconds?

Comment: You could send a sentinel value from your client which the server recognizes which makes it break out of its loop.

Comment: *"If I do not receive data (e.g. for 30 sec.) the server shall close a socket."* - So you need to have a timeout for recv. Therefore marked as duplicate of questions which ask how to implement a timeout for recv.